# How to convert MapResult from map! to array of ints?

Tags: algorithm, int, d

I need way to implicitly convert MapResult from [`map!`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm_iteration.html#map) template from type `auto` to `int []`. How can I do it?

```d
import std.stdio;
import std.conv;
import std.array;
import std.algorithm;

void main()
{
    string s = "1,3,5,6,8";

    int x [];
    // auto xx = s.split(",").map!(a => to!int(a)); // working code
     x = s.split(",").map!(a => to!int(a)); // not working
    writeln(x);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not possible implicitly, but explicitly with `array`:

```
int[] x = s.split(",").map!(a => a.to!int).array;
```

Comment: BTW, don't do this unless you actually *need* to if you want best performance - there's a reason it isn't done automatically or implicitly! If you just want to how the result, you can loop over without making the array.